# Access the members of the clusters formed by GMM in python

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means, gmm

I am new to `Python` and `GMM`. I am trying to cluster a text document. I followed the instructions given in this link to perform `GMM` clustering.

https://www.kaggle.com/dfoly1/gaussian-mixture-model/data

I got the visual view of the clusters. I am struggling with understanding the members of the cluster. I could easily check the top terms per cluster while using K-means but I am not able to figure out how to do it on the GMM model. 
Appreciate your time and help